# Scripting Data out of SQL Server versioned-tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a SQL Server database where all of the tables are system-versioned tables.

[image]

I get a full history of all changes. I can live with the table designer not working in SSMS, but I ran into a bigger issue when scripting out data.

Right-click the database and select Tasks -> Generate Scripts…  On the Set Script Options tab select Advanced and change “Types of data to script” to “Schema and data”.   It generates a script containing lines like:

```
INSERT [dbo].[AspNetUserRolesHistory] ([UserId], [RoleId], [StartTime], [EndTime]) 
VALUES (N'b0cfa598-0c2d-4c27-8ef0-3fbdf7d41b17', N'16712460-a3fd-4bdc-aded-2b93901fc199', 
CAST(N'2022-08-27T03:35:59.7402366' AS DateTime2), 
CAST(N'2022-08-27T03:40:43.0736925' AS DateTime2))
```

When I run this on the target database I get the error:

> Msg 13536, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table 'dbo.AspNetUserRoles'. 
> Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the GENERATED ALWAYS column, 
> or insert a DEFAULT into GENERATED ALWAYS column.

It is going to be test data so I don't care about the [StartTime], [EndTime] columns and I can easily search and replace the column names out. But the data part for these columns varies with each line.

```
CAST(N'2022-08-27T03:35:59.7402366' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2022-08-27T03:40:43.0736925' AS DateTime2)
```

Can’t easily search and replace them out because they are all different.   I tried replacing “CAST(N’” with “) --“, but these aren’t the only DateTime columns and I have thousands of rows.

Any way to do this without having to go through Excel?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of SSMS? Only thing I can think of (assuming you don't wnat to try a different tool) is to use Regex. For example find `, CAST\(.+?\), CAST\(.+?\)` and replace with empty string

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, v18.12.1   I would do the Regex, except I have other columns I need to keep.

Comment: Stepping back (at least) one step, given that you're saying that this is going to be test data, would you be okay with converting your table to a non-temporal table in the test system, inserting the data into what will become the history table, and then attaching the history to the live table with `ALTER TABLE ... SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = ...));`?